# Recoved deleted rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

After running a query like

```
 delete from table tablename
```

Can the records be recovered? From what I know Postgresql is just marking the records as deleted.

Comment: I wrote a more detailed answer about this on another question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss/12472582#12472582

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [pg file dump](https://web.archive.org/web/20170523054557/http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pgfiledump).

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210213044/http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/How-to-Make-a-pg-filedump-td4264125.html).

**EDIT:** In the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_filedump) you can find the [pg file dump](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pg_filedump.git;a=blob;f=README.pg_filedump) [git repository](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pg_filedump.git).

Comment: thank you! Do you have any more details? I would like to access a specific table on a spacific database and after reading the source (there is no other documentation) i'm not really sure how to proceed. Also, this is a production database.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Your question prompted me to google it. It's being maintained by Tom Lane, though, so chances are he'll reply himself if you ask for help on the pg-hackers list.

Comment: If you need help that doesn't involve actually hacking the code, ask your question on pgsql-general, not hackers.  -hackers is for hacking code, not asking for support.

Comment: You should also check out `pg_dirtyread`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss/12472582#12472582

Comment: The links don't seem to be working any more. Is there an updated link, or an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: @spinningarrow: this answer is from years ago, but try: http://pgsql-hackers.postgresql.narkive.com/xP51LFSQ/how-to-make-a-pg-filedump and https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pg_filedump