# Restore deleted records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I accidentally deleted all the records from 3 tables in PostgreSQL. How can i restore the data?

Comment: Have you got a database backup from yesterday?

Comment: i got nothing,,, is there any recovery method?

Comment: You're probably out of luck. I think [Craig Ringer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) wrote a big answer about this but it might be over on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: can't i do anything to get my data back??

Comment: @user236928 Not without serious data recovery expertise, which costs serious money. You told the database to delete the data, so it did. Recovery is only possible if the server hasn't yet overwritten the data. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a similar problem as discussed here:

[Can I rollback a transaction I've already committed? (data loss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss)

Basically, restore from backup. If you can't, you *might* be able to recover with `pg_dirtyread`.

If you don't have backups, stop the whole server, take a disk image of the drive, and contact a $lots data recovery expert.