# how to write function for recover deleted information if needed in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

i am trying to created some function when column or table in **postgreSQL** database deleted
function show delete information and recovery information **without** third party application (pitrery,pg-barman)

Comment: If the data is really deleted, you cannot recover it. But maybe you want to write some kind of historization. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Try read answer in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss)

Comment: `...  and ask me do you want to recovery?(yes/no) ...` - this is not a job for a database server