# SQLAlchemy(Python)/Sequelize(Node.js) rollback transation (undo button)

Tags: python, node.js, sqlalchemy, sequelize.js

So I am right now developing a backend API using GraphQL and either Python with SQLAlchemy or Node.js with Sequelize to write all the data into a SQLite database.

I am still not sure what backend I will end up with. Maybe this question and the answer to my question will lead me to using one or the other.

So my app will have a function where you add dart throws (like double 20, triple 19, ...) into a table with throws. Depending on the game chosen and the conditions chosen this throw will either substract from a total count or maybe be added into a counter table or something like that.

Everytime a throw gets added there will be a check if the game is won and some other checks as well. Those might also write (commit) data to the database.

Now, if the user types in the wrong number / or the automatic darts machine will discover the wrong throw number (malfunction) there is a throw and several changed data in the database which I will have to rollback.

In darts scorer apps you will find in the app store either ios or android you always will have a undo button which will erase the throw from the database and all the "effects" caused by entering the wrong throw.

As a former mssql administrator my first idea was transactional logs and rollback function. But after searching the net for a while I understand both SQLAlchemy and Sequelize will rollback transactions only on exception.

Can I purposely rollback the last "complete" transaction (meaning all changes which for example a function will make by the end of the function) by hitting a button / calling a rest api path like '/undo' and if so are there any code snippets for either SQLAlchemy or Sequelize I am missing?

Best regards,
Patrick

### edit:

collection of provided answers:

- command pattern (python)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Can I rollback a transaction I've already committed? (data loss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss) and other sources, no, you cannot rollback a committed transaction. Also this is DB dependent, so doesn't have to do much with ORM or language.

I would recommend to implement the [Command pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_command.htm), which is great for [Undo](https://medium.com/@sean_bradley/undo-redo-pattern-in-python-70ade29644b3). So basically do the revert from code, not from the database.

Comment: So you say it is database dependend. Would using mysql/mariadb or postgresql would change the ability to use rollbacks then? Cause if so I will not hestitate to do so, as I am already using ORM it will not bother me switching backends, I guess?

Comment: not sure if there is a DB which supports this, but rollbacks in general are when something went wrong, but your scenario works best by using the code.

Comment: I looked at the provided links using command pattern. That might be way over the top concerning my code. Please don't take it wrong but that is more complicated than I am able to handle by the moment.

Comment: I read more about the command pattern and watched a few Videos. I understand I would have to maintain a Stack of commands which I later on could reference to undo Actions. But as my App is api driven (flask routes) I will not have a object to instanciate and refer to later on. So command pattern will not work, right? @horatiu