# How can I revert or rollback the database changes made during testing using 'tap' after test is completed?

Tags: node.js, database, testing, tap, fastify

I am using **tap** framework for testing my node application. While running the test I am making some changes in the database.

I want to revert all the changes made in the database after testing. Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: You have followed the wrong approach, you put changes without backup the database, that is wrong. by the way which Database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgres database

Comment: Is there any option for that in the tap framework itself?

Comment: No, I don't think there is any option. well what kind of changes you have done?

Comment: I have created a new record in the table and deleted one record

Comment: I have posted an answer to your problem. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't undo, rollback or reverse a commit.

Basically, restore from backup. If you can't, you might be able to recover with `**pg_dirtyread**`.

If you don't have backups, stop the whole server, take a disk image of the drive, and contact a $lots data recovery expert.

If you have committed the transaction, you cannot rollback or undo the update. Please find the detailed answer here.

There is one article about this `pg_dirtyread` [here](https://medium.com/@ravisharma_60668/lets-read-dirty-91a8f0cc4fdf) on medium.

[Can I rollback a transaction I've already committed? (data loss)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss/12472582#12472582)