# How do I avoid accidentally deleting postgres table rows?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres. It seems very easy to accidentally delete all of a table's data.

For example, I tried to delete one table row and accidentally deleted the whole table contents. This is no problem; the table contained mock data. However, the tables that I create in the future will contain important data.

Example of very easy deletion:

```
polls_db=# DELETE from polls_choice;
DELETE 8
```

Is there an easy way in Postgres to restore table data, or to soft delete table data whereby the data can be easily restored?

Comment: You can create a role on db server with NO permission to delete operations and assign that role to a user and use that user only to perform actions.

Comment: Another thing that will help is not to run SQL statements by hand.

Comment: Make it a habit to always run `begin;` before running any dml statements directly

Comment: Related: [How to rollback an update in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12880994/190597)